# Print 2D int array to screen

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My code is reading a `txt` file and then its parsing it into a 2D table.

Anyone knows why when I print my table with

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tableau));
```

I see that the 1st line only contains a bunch of `0`?

Here is my code and the content of the `txt` file im parsing:

```
014 116 218 313 411 517 615 712 819 022 127 225 324 428 529 623 726
821 031 133 239 335 436 532 637 734 838 045 148 246 349 447 541 642
743 844 057 159 252 356 454 553 651 758 855 063 161 264 362 465 568
669 767 866 079 174 273 371 472 576 678 775 877 086 182 287 388 489
585 684 781 883 098 195 291 397 493 594 696 799 892
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class Sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            int[][] tableau = new int[10][10];
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\lidaeg\\java\\sudoku\\partie3.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String texte = scanner.next();

                Character ligneID = (texte.charAt(1));
                Integer ligne = Character.getNumericValue(ligneID);

                Character colonneID = (texte.charAt(0));
                Integer colonne = Character.getNumericValue(colonneID);

                Character chiffreID = (texte.charAt(2));
                Integer chiffre = Character.getNumericValue(chiffreID);

                tableau[ligne][colonne] = chiffre;
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tableau));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println(" Fichier introuvable!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i understand you correct you device which "line" you wanto to put your values in by reading the numerical value of the second digit of your numbers with `Character ligneID = (texte.charAt(1));` + `Integer ligne = Character.getNumericValue(ligneID);`. But if you look at thhe file content you gave us you should see that there simply isn't a signle number that has `0` in the middle, so the fact that absolutely nothing gets put in `tableau[0]` should really come as no surprise at all.

Comment: thanks oh god spiders... i was using the wrong file its working now

Answer (score 0):

You are reading sudoku (or something like it), which is a 9 by 9 matrix, i.e 81 elements. But you are creating an integer array of 10 by 10 which has 100 elements, all defaulted to zero to start with. If you do not assign or override values then they will show up as zeroes.

Change the code to a 9 by 9 matrix and update the array assignment accordingly (arrays are zero-indexed)

Answer (score 0):

According to the input you provided, I assume, that ligne is starting with 1 and colonne is starting with 0.

A Sudoku as I know has 9x9 fields. Therefore you need to use an 9x9 Array:

```
int[][] tableau = new int[9][9];
```

Indexes of arrays are starting with 0 and the last index is the size of the array -1.
Because the ligne in your input filestarts with 1, you need to decrease this number when you want to get the correct position:

```
Integer ligne = Character.getNumericValue(ligneID-1);
```

The "bunch of 0" you get are the initial values of int-variables from your array. After the line `int[][] tableau = new int[9][9];` all values in the 2D-Array are 0. If you dont write other numbers to it, these 0 will stay. This is the reason for your output, when you use a 10x10.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains exactly 81 numbers in appropriate order, the scanner may use `nextInt()` method to read the integer values; also the column-row prefix may be discarded altogether by using `% 10`.

Example using Stream API looks as follows:

```java
public static int[][] readSudoku(Scanner input) {
    return IntStream.range(0, 9)
                    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 9)
                            .map(j -> input.nextInt() % 10)
                            .toArray()
                    )
                    .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Test

```java
public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(
        // new File("C:\\Users\\lidaeg\\java\\sudoku\\partie3.txt")
        "014 116 218 313 411 517 615 712 819 022 127 225 324 428 529 623 726 821 "
      + "031 133 239 335 436 532 637 734 838 045 148 246 349 447 541 642 743 844 "
      + "057 159 252 356 454 553 651 758 855 063 161 264 362 465 568 669 767 866 "
      + "079 174 273 371 472 576 678 775 877 086 182 287 388 489 585 684 781 883 "
      + "098 195 291 397 493 594 696 799 892"
    )) {
        int[][] sudoku = readSudoku(input);

        Arrays.stream(sudoku).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[4, 6, 8, 3, 1, 7, 5, 2, 9]
[2, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 6, 1]
[1, 3, 9, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8]
[5, 8, 6, 9, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 8, 5]
[3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6]
[9, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 5, 7]
[6, 2, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 1, 3]
[8, 5, 1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 9, 2]
```